# What is a better way to design an API for mutually exclusive request parameters?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, api-design

What is a better way to design an API on a @Controller method when request parameters are mutually exclusive?

Let's say that there is an API to provide a List of Users that matches the request parameters.

Code is:

```
public ResponseEntity getList(@RequestParam(required = false) Integer userId,
                              @RequestParam(required = false) User.Type userType,
                              @RequestParam(required = false) Integer age) {
        List<User> userList = null;
        if (userId != null) {
            //logic
            userList = getUserByUserId()
        } else if (userType != null) {
            //logic
            userList = getUserByType()
        } else if (age != null) {
            //logic
            userList = getListByAge()
        } else {
            userList = getAllWithoutCondition();
        }
        return ResponseEntity.ok(userList);
}
```

**Here is the point:**

The user cannot query with more than one request parameter. Only one request parameter or no request parameter is valid (only one of `userId`, `age`, or `type` should exist in a request).

I am not sure what the better way to design an API for this situation is. Can you give me some advice?

Comment: These restrictions look artificial. I would just accept to combine all the search criteria (or at least the last two. The first one shouldn't be a request param, but should be a path param of another resource allowing to get one user). But you could write three different methods, too. https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-params-and-headers

Comment: you aren't handling mutual exclusiveness of params, are you? (now I can pass `userId` and `userType` and it will work fine - I will get a list of users by id)

Comment: @JBNizet writing three different methods would cause ambiguous mapping - the endpoints would differ only in request params

Comment: No they wouldn't. Not if you use the annotation shown in the section of the documentation that I linked to.

Comment: is there any chance you could segregate these operations by mapping them to different URIs?

Comment: according to single responsibility principle (SRP) in SOLID , it is not recommended to have multi logic in a controller method, so as @AndrewTobilko also said, make sure you have separated methods for each logic corresponding to the request parameters.

Comment: I would have 3 methods, one for each parameter. That way you can remove all your `null` checks and have nice, clean, logic. You can map the methods to the same URL, Spring will match on parameters.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Spring can't match on params (it would cause ambiguous mapping, as I said before) unless you specify restrictions (by adding `params` as @JBNizet mentioned) which makes your endpoint definitions messy and unclear (like `params={"!type", "!age", ...}` for each method)

Comment: @AndrewTobilko true - I guess you do need the `!` params in there too; as well as the required param I mean

Comment: @BoristheSpider how would OP invoke the endpoint with no request params?

Comment: I would definitely go for three methods, but I would also question whether these three should be thought of as three variations of the same interface. The first ( by userId ) would almost certainly return zero or one users wouldn't it? Modelling that as a list seems artificial to me.

Comment: Actually, as many of you pointed out, userId should definitely be separated. It was my mistake while making example. What I meant was that three different requestParams that return userList.

Comment: @AndrewTobilko I thought it would be better to map these functions on same URI since all this logics are for querying userList on different condition. Could you give me some recommendation for different URI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like the approach suggested by the guys in the comments:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "...", params = {"!userType", "!userAge"})
public ResponseEntity<List<User>> getListByUserId(@RequestParam Integer userId) { ... }

// similarly, define two more
```

It looks robust and feasible until you start managing restrictions for each endpoint. It looks tedious and hard to maintain. Furthermore, I am not sure how the endpoint that takes no params would react. Would it get called or be shadowed by other methods?

Instead of writing restrictions, I suggest introducing conditions - the requirements for each endpoint. It could be a `Map<String, Function<String, List<User>>>` in the next format:

```
<param name> -> <action to get a list>
```

I also advise you collect all the incoming request params into a single `Map<String, String>` to validate it by size.

```
public class Controller {

    private Map<String, Function<String, List<User>>> handlers = new HashMap<>();

    {
        handlers.put("userId", id -> getUsersById(Integer.valueOf(id)));
        handlers.put("userType", type -> getUsersByType(User.Type.valueOf(type)));
        handlers.put("userAge", age -> getUsersByAge(Integer.valueOf(age)));
    }

    @RequestMapping("...")
    public ResponseEntity<List<User>> getList(@RequestParam Map<String, String> params) {
        if (params.size() > 1) {
            return ResponseEntity.unprocessableEntity().build();
        }

        if (params.size() == 0) {
            return ResponseEntity.ok(getAllWithoutCondition());
        }

        Map.Entry<String, String> paramEntry = params.entrySet().iterator().next();

        return ResponseEntity.ok(handlers.get(paramEntry.getKey()).apply(paramEntry.getValue()));
    }

    private List<User> getAllWithoutCondition() { ... }

    private List<User> getUsersById(Integer id) { ... }
    private List<User> getUsersByType(User.Type type) { ... }
    private List<User> getUsersByAge(Integer age) { ... }

}
```

Comment: good solution but I think readability will be sacrificed to some degree

Comment: @akarimin there is absolutely no reason to use a `ConcurrentHashMap` as the `Map` is not mutated after instatiation.

Comment: This is a nice idea, but does it work with api doc generators? (swagger, spring-rest-docs, etc...) My guess is not.

Mutual-exclusivity doesn't seem to be supported by spring. Even the first approach with `params = {"!userType", "!userAge"}` doesn't work because this list is concatenated with OR logic. Which makes it logically wrong.

I am also facing the same issue currently and I don't think there is any good solution. I'm leaning towards implementing a custom annotation.